# Copy excel range to new xlsx file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the below code to copy a range from a macro enabled workbook to a new excel file that then gets sent on to a company.

The code worked when saving the new file as a csv but I noticed it lost the formatting so I need to save it as an excel file.

I get a runtime error 1004 and message to say method save as of object workbook failed.

The only change I made was taking the .csv extension and changing to .xlsx.

```
Sub exportJuneCredit()
     '
     ' export Macro

    Range("A1:H500").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "file path Credits.xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlsx, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It actually looks like you also changed `FileFormat:=xlCSV` to `FileFormat:=xlsx`, which isn't a recognised format.  You probably want `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: -

```
Sub exportJuneCredit()
    Dim WkSht_Src   As Worksheet
    Dim WkBk_Dest   As Workbook
    Dim WkSht_Dest  As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set WkSht_Src = ActiveSheet
        Set Rng = WkSht_Src.Range("A1:H500")
            Set WkBk_Dest = Application.Workbooks.Add
                Set WkSht_Dest = WkBk_Dest.Worksheets(1)
                    Rng.Copy WkSht_Dest.Range("A1")
                Set WkSht_Dest = Nothing
                WkBk_Dest.SaveAs Filename:="file path Credits.xlsx", FileFormat:=XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, CreateBackup:=False
                WkBk_Dest.Close 0
            Set WkBk_Dest = Nothing
        Set Rng = Nothing
    Set WkSht_Src = Nothing

End Sub
```

The issue I believe you were having was that `activeworkbook` may not have been the workbook you wanted to save, to get around this I have explicitly declared items.

I also change the copy/paste to use just the copy feature.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Although would not let me open file after it was created. Changed the file format to: xlOpenXMLWorkbook as mentioned by YowE3K.

Comment: You hardcoded the range. Is there a way to dynamically set the range to the last row which contains data?

Comment: Something like `WkSht.Range("A1:H" & WkSht.Range("A" & wksht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Address` would do it. The `end(xlUP)` is the important part

Answer (score 0):

> Although would not let me open file after it was created. Changed the file format to: xlOpenXMLWorkbook as mentioned by YowE3K. – PA060 Jun 12 '17 at 11:42

The code given by Gary Evans is to save as the backward compatible .xls format. If you change the filename to have .xls as extension it will allow you to open.

If you want .xlsx file, then change file format to xlOpenXMLWorkbook as mentioned by YowE3K.